# Unity3D manipulate object orientation with respect to original orientation

Tags: unity-game-engine, orientation, quaternions

I encountered another issue with hand-object interaction using a Leap Motion device. In particular, I use the LM to perform orientation manipulations on virtual objects.

I want to use the difference between the current and last orientation of the hand to manipulate the object:

```
Quaternion relativeOrientationHands = Quaternion.Inverse(currentHandOrientation) * updatedHand;
transform.rotation = transform.rotation * relativeOrientationHands;
```

It works fine, however the problem is that, let's say I rotate the object 180 degrees around the x axis (after that, y is pointing downwards). If I release the object afterwards, and grasp it again, the orientation changes get from then on applied to the new orientation of the object which is super confusing to use. (Original: turn hand to the left - object turns counter-clockwise; After: turn hand to the left - object turns clockwise)

[image][image][image]

Unfortunately, I don't know the math to fix it, but maybe someone can help me out. How can I apply the orientation changes of the hand to my virtual object, with respect to the default object orientation using Quaternions. Maybe, something with normal vectors?

**EDIT:**

The 3 figures illustrate my problem. The first figure shows the object in its original orientation (x-right, y-upwards). I turn the cube 180 degrees by rotating my hand 180 degrees clockwise around z (blue axis), after I release it, x is pointing to the left and y is pointing downwards (figure 2). If I grasp the object (figure 3) in its current orientation, and let's say I would want to perform a 90 degrees clockwise rotation around the y-axis. In figure one, I could do that by moving my hand 90 degrees clockwise. However, I changed the orientation of the cube with my previous manipulation. Therefore, I would have to perform a 90 degrees counter-clockwise rotation with my hand to move the object in clockwise direction, because the y-axis is flipped (figure 2-3). I always want that turning your hand 90 degrees clockwise results in a 90 degrees clockwise rotation of the object regardless of its current orientation.

Thank you very much

Best
R.Devel

Comment: I don't absolutly get your problem, but if I am, i want you to ask, did you see that behaviour on the LM samples or demos? like the Blocks demo?

Comment: @Lotan thank you for your answer. I tried to clarify the question. Yes, I know their demo, however we aim to develop an alternative approach =) They used the grasping angle as a rotation axis which we don't want to do.